# What is the definite integral from c to c of a function that is undefined at x=c?

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals

Since when $f(x)$ is undefined at $x=c$ and $a \leq c \leq b$

$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$

is undefined as it takes the definite integral over an undefined region of the function. Or in another sense, since all definite integrals that cover an undefined portion of $f(x)$ are undefined.

And since

$\int_{a}^{a}f(x)dx=0$

is considered true (at least to my understanding) for any value, $a$, and any function, $f(x)$. Does that make

$\int_{c}^{c}f(x)dx=0$

or

$\int_{c}^{c}f(x)dx$ undefined

When $f(x)$ is undefined at $x=c$?

Comment: Use this definition for your integral: $$\lim_{b \to 0} \int_{c-b}^{c+b} f(x)dx$$

Comment: Actually $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ is a sloppy notation. What exactly is meant by it? There several candidates: $\int f(x)1_{[a,b]}(x)dx$ is one of them, but why not e.g. $\int f(x)1_{(a,b]}(x)dx$. In the later case $\int_c^cf(x)dx=\int f(x)0dx=\int0dx=0$. Nevertheless if $f$ is not defined at $c$ then you could argue that also $f(x)0$ is not defined at $c$. If the integrand is not defined properly then the integral is not defined properly.

Comment: Seriously, these two articles will explain a lot: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)

Comment: I don't know anybody who would consider $\int_{a}^{a}f(x)dx=0$ to be true if $f(a)$ isn't even defined. It's true for integrable functions, not for undefined functions.

Comment: @ProfessorVector, the OP quite clearly asks exactly this, if it's true or not. They are not claiming it is true if the function is not defined. The function not defined at some point is not a function at this point. We can talk about distributions though, which is why I think the question is perfectly valid

Comment: @Yuriy S But distributions aren't functions, sorry! I'm afraid the OP doesn't even understand his own question, let alone your interpretation of it.

Comment: @ProfessorVector, I do not see any harm in providing them with proper terms and links so they better understand the topic. Education is one of the main goals of this site, I believe

Comment: @ProfessorVector Distributions are functions. They are linear functionals, which are functions.

$\int_a^bf=\int_a^bg$ iff $\{x|f(x)\neq g(x)\}$ has measure zero, so you can define function $\tilde{f}$ st $\tilde{f}=f$ for all $x\neq c$ and $\tilde{f}(c)=C$ for some arbitrary constant $C$, and their integrals will be equal.